# Creating synthetic frequency domain box filter vs 4 pixels in corners

Tags: frequency-domain, fourier

Creating two 10x10 black images.
1st image, adding a 2x2 white box in the middle (Low pass filter).
2nd image, adding 1 pixel in each of the corners.

Then performing the following steps in that order:
1. ifft2 (Transformation to the time domain)
2. ifftshift (Without it the results would be shifted, not sure why, and shift before the ifft2 would not help).
3. Normalize the results to emphasize the changes.
4. Show the results as images.

Why am I getting the same results out of the two images we created above?

I tried to explain my question the best I could, but here are images of the two frequency domain and then their result:

[image: Here]